# How do I store multiple values generated in a for loop to pass to a funtion within a tkinter button loop?

Tags: python, image, function, button, tkinter

I have a tkinter window that builds the necessary number of buttons, names them accordingly, and then displays a corresponding image. I want the button to print the correct filename that corresponds to the image when pressed. I tried `lambda`, but that will only pass the last argument. How can I do this?

`images` is a list of filenames from the directory I'm using.

```
def print_filename(i):
    print(i)


window = Tk()
window.title('Test Window')

for i in images:
    my_image = PhotoImage(master = window, file = i)
    label = Label(window, image = my_image)
    label.image=my_image
    label.grid(row = 1, column = c)
    b = Button(window, text=f'button {(c+1)}', command=lambda: print_filename(i))
    b.grid(row=0, column=c)
    c += 1

window.mainloop()
```

This is what it looks like when it runs:

[image: Image of Program running]

The button should print out the filename of the Image when pressed.
For example: `pdf_1.png`

Comment: Try `command=lambda i=i: print_filename(i)` and let me know

Comment: That did it! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

From *Tkinter*'s documentation:

*Tkinter’s Button widget doesn’t pass any information to the callback.*

*For simple cases like this, you can use a lambda expression as a link between Tkinter and the callback function:*

```py
def callback(number):
   print(number) 

Button(text="one",   command=lambda: callback(1)).pack()
Button(text="two",   command=lambda: callback(2)).pack()
Button(text="three", command=lambda: callback(3)).pack()
```

Use the way mentioned above to pass the index of the image to `print_filename`.

Comment: The OP seems to be using python 3.x